# java - android - why serialize before storing to file?

Tags: java, android, file, serialization, storage

### Context:

I want to store an object to a file.

I know the size of each and so the overall size of the object.
There is no networking involved : just local storage read/write.

In C, I store my structure like that for performance reasons (again, just local data, and no, it will not bite: I control the size and no pointers are involved, obviously).

### Question:

Everyone wants me to serialize first. All the tutos serialize first.

**"do it because it is like that"** -> Performance hit.

Why isn't it conceavable to store the whole object in file and get that later in java ( <-> hidden pointer somewhere ?) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030642/write-java-objects-to-file

Comment: What is "do it because it is like that" -> Performance hit." supposed to mean? What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is** conceivable to store the whole object in file Java in your own way.

Everyone just recommends you serialization cause there is built-in mechanism in Java that does exactly that: saves content of the object to a file.

So instead of writing you own code you just add `implements Serializable` to your class definition and you can save it a file with simple:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("your file")) {
    out.writeObject(yourObject);
}
```

If you want to implement it yourself, you can but of course it will take more than those 3 lines of code and you would need to test it and fix bugs. And once you change your object definition you need to fix your writing and reading methods ...

So it is just convenience and a smart convenience as Java serialization can handle a lot of 'difficult cases as well' (for example cycles in objects graph).

Typically you would start with serialization as your base mechanism, which then you can tune further. For example you are not happy with the output file size (serialization being 'general' approach has a lot of overhead for simple data structure). You can take care of part of the serializaation process yourself to make it more optimal.

For example you could implement `Externalizable` instead of `Serializable` and implement:

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in)
```

and inside those methods code/decode whole your object content as one String with some delimiter for the fields.

You can also store your object as xml by putting `@XmlRootElement` on top of your class and using JAXB (again whole saving will take 3 lines of code).

There are JSON libriaries as well.

Simply, it is easier as safer to use build in mechanism, that are tested to work instead of writing your own ones.

Comment: Understood ! Thanks I like the writeObject thing. Will use that ! Bye

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points yet to add a comment, but, I wanted to follow up with Zielu's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577482/789358.

If you want to lessen the performance hit of the default marshalling/demarshalling, Java does provide another mechanism for which you can manually persist objects. But, it definitely requires a bit more book-keeping from you.

To do this, implement `Externalizable` instead of `Serializable`. This will force you to implement two more methods:

```
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException;
```

[Here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/?page=6) is a good comparison of `Serializable` performance versus `Externalizable`. And [here](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/externalization.php) is a good intro on how to get started with implementing `Externalizable`.

You can also work at an even more granular level using the `RandomAccessFile` class, which might be closer to C-style as it involves tracking the file pointer based on byte sizes of the elements in your object. You can find an example online of that class usage pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks gman ! that is a very good addition ! +1