# Android equivalent for KeyedArchiver like Ios

Tags: android, ios, view, nskeyedarchiver

In Ios UIKit we have

```
let vyuDataVar = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(namVccVar.view)
```

which helps in converting entire view and all subviews as data and can be stored anywhere and we can retrieve our View back even after app closes.

What is the equivalent for this in android to convert entire activities view and store?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575975/java-android-why-serialize-before-storing-to-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this in Android, sorry.

Comment: @SujayUN: Not really. Android apps, like Web apps and most other computer software, do not store user interfaces. They store data, which you can then pour into a user interface that is created as needed (e.g., Android layout resource inflation). So, our focus in Android app development is storing our data in SQLite, `SharedPreferences`, or other sorts of files.